# よい変数名（定数名）を付けたい

Tags: javascript

下記のvalueに適切な変数名を付けたいです。要件は下部に列挙します。

```
var value = 1000; // これ

if (cart.totalPrice < value) {
    handlingCharge = 100;
}
```

処理としては、`カートの合計金額が1000未満の場合、手数料を100にする`です。
内容は抽象化しています。

value は設定として外部に持たせるつもりですので、変数というより定数です。
一応、handlingChargeも定数ですので外部に持たせます。

要件:
 1. 英語
 2. わかりやすく、処理内容に沿った名前
 3. 省略をしない(quantityをqtyにする様なものはダメ)　-> 長くても良いと考えています。
 4. 最終的には、Upper Camel Caseにします

ちなみに、センスの無い私が考えたのは

`MinimumPriceForHandlingCharge`
`ThresholdOfHandlingCharge`

辺りで、なにかダサく、なにか腑に落ちない気持ち悪さを感じてしまっているので、みなさまの知恵をお借りできればと思います。

Comment: メソッド名やフラグ変数に比べて、案外、定数名の方が難しいと感じることはありますよね。私でしたら、MinimumPurchaseAmount(最低購入金額)とか思いつきました。こちらのサイトも参考になるかもしれません。http://nelog.jp/programming-words

Comment: サイトはとても参考になりました。仰るとおり、定数の命名で悩むことが多い気がします。
`MinimumPurchaseAmount`(最低購入金額)は結構よいと思いますが、少しニュアンスがずれる感覚を持ちます。
こちらの説明が不足しているためかと思いますが、**ユーザに対して、最低購入金額は設定しません。**

Answer (score 5):

アメリカのアマゾンの送料無料の説明などを参考にしてみましたが `MinimumOrderForFreeHandling` とか `MinimumFreeHandlingOrder` あたりでどうでしょうか。

Comment: `MinimumOrderForFreeHandling`がとてもしっくりきます。
確かにAmazonやPaypalのAPIはとても参考になります。
こういった長い命名の場合に、前置詞（ForやOf）を付けるべきかどうか悩む節がありますが、必要最低限ですね。

Answer (score 0):

`NeedPriceForFreeOfHandlingCharge`ってのは如何？
更に削って`NeedPriceForFreeHandling`

エキサイト翻訳：もし購入金額が1000円未満なら、手数料として100円頂きます
If the purchase price is less than [1000 yen], I'll have 100 yen as a handling charge.

この英文をそのままソースコードに落としこむとこうなります。

```
if (the_purchase_price < 1000_yen) {
  handling_charge = 100;
}
```

この1000円を名詞化するならば「形容詞がゴテゴテ付いた超長い名詞になる」はずです
（英語は単語単語が単純である代わりに、沢山形容詞を付けるものなので…）

@Hideki さんが挙げているように「Free」という単語、
もしくはそれに代わる何かが必須でこれがなければ何を説明してる名詞なのかわかりません。

私もあまり英語が得意ではないのですが、
私だったらこの変数名にするなと思ったので書き込んでみます。

Comment: needという動詞が先頭にくるのは名詞句としておかしいですし、purchase price は注文の合計金額ではなく商品の購入価格（http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/purchase+price）なので意味合いが異なるかと。そのあたりはHidekiさんの `MinimumOrderForFreeHandling` の方がしっくりきます。

Comment: 色々と調べなおしました。
needは名詞でもある動詞ですが、名詞にくっつけると動詞以外ありえないので、形容詞化(necessary)する必要がありました。
purchase price ですが、purchase price for the itemとか、total of purchase priceとか、形容詞を付けて限定しなければ曖昧なワードですね…この辺は別にorderにしても解決はしないかと思います。
orderで料金と簡単に表す例文も調べたら出てきて、Hidekiさんの案はなるほどしっくり来るなと思ってます。